# ActivityIndicator not showing in XAML or CodeBehind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a weird situation on my Xamarin.Forms app. I´m trying to show an ActivityIndicator, but it is not showing in any condition. I´ve set all conditions on XAML and then I tried on code behind. But I could not get it to work. This is the code:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" 
             VerticalOptions="Center">
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actIndicator" 
                       Color="Blue" 
                       IsVisible="True" 
                       IsRunning="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblCargando" 
           Text="Cargando..." />
    <Label x:Name="lblStatus"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnCerrar" 
            Text="Cerrar" 
            IsVisible="False" 
            Clicked="Cerrar_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Is there something missing?.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried the classical solution: delete 'bin' and 'obj', clean, rebuild, re-run? Your code seems ok

Comment: Try giving it a width and height to rule it out

Comment: Please attach more code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it seems that there was an issue with the emulator that was executing an old version of code.
I deleted the emulator and re create it and get rid of the problem.